# Access the keyframe of css3 animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've found that there is a function called `WebKitCSSKeyframesRule` in the window object, but it seems that executing this function leads to an error. Does anyone know how this function works? Is there a good way to modify the keyframe of css3 animation?

Comment: I *think* that's an internal function in webkit: http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-658.28/css/WebKitCSSKeyframesRule.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebKitCSSKeyframesRule` isn't a function: it's a *contructor* that's used internally when parsing stylesheets.

To modify a `@keyframes` rule, you have to find it first:

```
var styleSheet = document.styleShees[0], keyframesRule;

for (var i = 0; i < styleSheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
    if (styleSheet.cssRules[i].type === CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) {
        keyframesRule = styleSheet.cssRules[i];
        break;
    }
}
alert(keyframesRule instanceof WebKitCSSKeyframesRule); // alerts "true"
```

Once you have your rule, you can modify, add, delete frame rules using the rule's `cssRules` property and the `addRule`, `deleteRule` methods, like you usually do with common stylesheets:

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyframesRule.cssRules.length; i++)
    alert(keyframesRule.cssRules[i].keyText + " { "
            + keyframesRule.cssRules[i].style.cssText + " }");
```

That's the same as alerting `keyframesRule.cssRules[i].cssText`.

Obviously, this is all *vendor prefixed*, so for Firefox you'll have to use `MozCSSKeyframesRule` instead, and so on.